# MS Lightswitch - How to set session variable shared across silverlight web client and asp.net pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, session-variables, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am using MS Lightswitch with Silverlight web client, also for reporting purpose I am using asp.net webforms to host crystal reports. Now I want to share some variables/data from lightswitch silverlight to asp.net webform.

One method is to pass simple values in query string, but now I have to pass value through session. Is there any way how to do it?

Application is hosted in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

```
// Screen code
 //========================== 
   partial void HelpScreen_InitializeDataWorkspace(List<IDataService> saveChangesTo)
    {
        // Use CompanyID in screens.
        int coID = Application.CompanyID;
    }
//Application.cs code //===================

    // Application.cs in Client UserCode
    partial void Application_LoggedIn()
    {
        if (Application.Current.User.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // Get your company ID here using a query that makes sense for your need.
            using (var ws = Application.Current.CreateDataWorkspace())
            {
                string cUser = Application.Current.User.Name;
                var contact = ws.ApplicationData.Contacts.Where(c => c.UserName == cUser).FirstOrDefault();
                if (contact != null)
                    CompanyID = contact.Id;
            }
        }
    }
```